# Material Design Graph for Android

Tags: android, graph, charts, material-design

I am trying to implement a material design graph in my app, but fail to accomplish this. All the graph libraries seem to lack the material design I am looking for, is there a method to change an existing library to make it have material design or to make one on your own?

Comment: material design is a theme, if the library does not support that theme then there is no "method" to change it

Answer (score 0):

Material Design is only a "guideline" from Google to create a common way to design the UI of app (not only graphical, but gestures and so no). Or the library has some Material Design elements, or you have to create them on your own.